# Двойной клик перестал работать

Tags: windows-xp, мышь

Вирус-поисковик - WebAlta покоцал ОСь (ХРошую СП3).
Я вынес его из реестра, теперь ярлычки открывают приложения  только по правой кнопке мыши "Открыть" при двойном клике вообще ни чего не происходит.
Как это устранить?про Рипэир понятно, и накачивание второй раз СП3.
Раз реестр юзал, значит там был ключ на действия по клику, WebAlta туда чего-то прописал видать, я под одну гребёнку вычистил все его записи напрочь.

Comment: http://yandex.ua/yandsearch?text=%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA+-+WebAlta&clid=1923016&lr=961

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо назначит действие "Open" как дефолтное

А что у Вас в реестре в узле

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk`

И есть ли запись об "LNK" в списке на вкладке "Типы файлов" для

"Мой компьютер"->"Сервис"->"Свойство папки"`

Comment: Вот про LNK в свойстве папки, там что за приложение должно с ним ассоциироваться?в реестре это:http://krasnoyarsk.front.ru/temp/regedit.jpg

Comment: Узел ShellNew - это для создания новых, а что прописано в в каждом из подузлов ShellEx ? И что там насчет `"Мой компьютер"->"Сервис"->"Свойство папки"` ?

Comment: Там у всех четырех ключей один параметр - {00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}Уже читаю[это...](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT%5C.lnk&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Comment: [А вот и решение!!!](http://www.sibadmin.ru/component/option,com_simplefaq/task,answer/Itemid,46/catid,3/aid,71/)Home, Спасибо за подталкивание к действию ;)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы переставил систему и поменял антивирус.

Comment: А я за то, что бы лечить больного, а не отрубать ему руку, если на ней бородавка и пришивать другую.На счёт антивируса, то ни какой антивирус не засечёт вирус с новым алгоритмом действий (не подходящий под анализ эвристики), пока он не получит достаточного распространения.

Comment: С 25 октября вполне можно было переставить систему.